# Neck swinging to barbell on eccentric of barbell row

Tags: barbell-rows

I've noticed my neck swings to the barbell when I'm doing the concentric on the lift. Is this harmful? If so, how could I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to correct neck position, the easiest way is to mark a fixed point on the ground before starting (so that your back and neck are in good alignment) and fix that point with your eyes while doing the rows. Can be your bottle, your cabin keys, a piece of tape or whatever.

The head tries to centre the eyes, the neck tries to align the head, so use your point of focus to help your body control your neck.

In case you are talking about a transverse movement instead of a swing (head moving forward *without change of angle* relative to the upper body), pulling the head back into a double chin and holding it there as default position might help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The fixed position goes out of the Mind when doing the exercise as I'm doing it as ab explosive lift.

What works is, decreasing the angle about hip. As in, turn the barbell row into more of a pendlay row.